Is `f.splitting_field()` a one-way function candidate?
Is computing the splitting field of a polynomial a candidate for a one-way function?
Let $K$ be a number field and $f, g \in K[x]$. Let L_f = f.splitting_field() and L_g = g.splitting_field(). It's certainly possible that $f\ne g$ and $L_f = L_g$. Polynomials are typically encoded by their coefficients, and number fields are given by their defining polynomials. I'm aware that not being one-to-one is not a sufficient condition.

What do you mean by "defining polynomials"? If $L=K(\alpha)$ is given by the minimal polynomial $h$ of $\alpha$, which is the usual representation, then  $h$ itself is a polynomial whose splitting field over $K$ is $L$ (assuming $L/K$ is normal, which it must be for it to be the splitting field of any polynomial). Even more generally, if $L$ is given by a finite set of generators, it is the splitting field of e.g. the product of their minimal polynomials. So this is in no way a one-way function.

@EmilJeřábek By defining polynomial let's use the LMFDB def: https://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/nf.polredabs. Sure, a minimal polynomial $h$ for the algebraic number $\alpha$ which generates $L$ exists. I'm confused though - how does imply "this is in no way a one-way function". Is it easy to invert .splitting_field()? Isn't the pre-image (the set of $f$ such that $L_f = L$) large?

That's not what inverting a potential one-way function means. It is enough to compute one preimage, not the set of all preimages (which is actually infinite here).

@EmilJeřábek It's a bit confusing. Math folks say "well, it's not invertible, so we can't talk about how hard it is to invert", whereas CS people are saying "well, all you need is one preimage, so just take the defining polynomial which is the minimal polynomial to be that element." I don't understand how the information loss in computing $L_f = L_g = L_h$ doesn't imply .splitting_field() is hashing its input in some way.

The definition is the way it is because it leads to a nontrivial and useful notion. Calling functions hard to invert for the trivial reason that the set of preimages is too large would lead to the absurd result that the most difficult one-way function is the constant-$0$ function, which is obviously useless for any cryptographic purposes.

@EmilJeřábek Okay, but this isn’t shedding much light on the situation at hand. I don’t know how big the preimage set is, nor how hard it is to compute. What I’m really curious about is if I keep $f$ secret, is it feasible to find $f$ given the data of $L$. In this case the output is essentially a polynomial, $g$, which happens to be the same format as the input. Saying that "well, $L_g = L$, so we're done since $g$ is in the preimage" is a bit like saying the output of multiplication is $n$, and $n=1\cdot n$ so we're done since $(1,n) \mapsto n$.

It's impossible to compute the particular $f$ you started with from $L=L_f$, since there is no way of knowing which of the infinitely many polynomials that give this same $L$ you used to construct the extension. This does not make the problem computationally hard, but ill-defined.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
